# Clustered Wildfly throws java.lang.IllegalAccessError

Tags: java, wildfly, infinispan, undertow

I'm running application on Wildfly managed domain that consists from 2 virtual machines with 3 servers on each VM.

Exception occurs in console.log:

```
14:04:10,254 WARN  [org.jboss.weld.Servlet] (default task-51) WELD-000717: Unable to deactivate context org.jboss.weld.context.http.HttpRequestContextImpl@2ec2ea52 when destroying request HttpServletRequestImpl [ GET /orpon/ ]
14:04:10,254 WARN  [org.jboss.weld.Servlet] (default task-51) WELD-000717: Unable to deactivate context org.jboss.weld.context.http.HttpSessionContextImpl@f171e22 when destroying request HttpServletRequestImpl [ GET /orpon/ ]
14:04:10,254 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-51) Undertow request failed HttpServerExchange{ GET /orpon/}: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Can not set final int field io.undertow.util.HttpString.hashCode to (int)-1978065285
    at io.undertow.util.HttpString.readObject(HttpString.java:340)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor167.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_66]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) [rt.jar:1.8.0_66]
    at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.SerializableClass.callReadObject(SerializableClass.java:307)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doInitSerializable(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1644)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadNewObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1285)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:276)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockUnmarshaller.readObject(BlockUnmarshaller.java:149)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockUnmarshaller.readObject(BlockUnmarshaller.java:135)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.MarshallerObjectInputStream.readObjectOverride(MarshallerObjectInputStream.java:53)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverObjectInputStream.readObjectOverride(RiverObjectInputStream.java:307)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:365) [rt.jar:1.8.0_66]
    at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1394) [rt.jar:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor157.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_66]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) [rt.jar:1.8.0_66]
    at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.SerializableClass.callReadObject(SerializableClass.java:307)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doInitSerializable(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1637)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadNewObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1285)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:276)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:224)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.readFields(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1745)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doInitSerializable(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1658)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadNewObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1285)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:276)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockUnmarshaller.readObject(BlockUnmarshaller.java:149)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockUnmarshaller.readObject(BlockUnmarshaller.java:135)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.MarshallerObjectInputStream.readObjectOverride(MarshallerObjectInputStream.java:53)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverObjectInputStream.readObjectOverride(RiverObjectInputStream.java:307)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:365) [rt.jar:1.8.0_66]
    at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1396) [rt.jar:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor157.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_66]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) [rt.jar:1.8.0_66]
    at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.SerializableClass.callReadObject(SerializableClass.java:307)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doInitSerializable(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1637)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadNewObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1285)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:276)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:209)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractObjectInput.readObject(AbstractObjectInput.java:41)
    at org.wildfly.clustering.marshalling.SimpleMarshalledValue.get(SimpleMarshalledValue.java:101)
    at org.wildfly.clustering.marshalling.SimpleMarshalledValue.get(SimpleMarshalledValue.java:45)
    at org.wildfly.clustering.marshalling.MarshalledValueMarshaller.read(MarshalledValueMarshaller.java:45)
    at org.wildfly.clustering.marshalling.MarshalledValueMarshaller.read(MarshalledValueMarshaller.java:32)
    at org.wildfly.clustering.web.infinispan.session.coarse.CoarseSessionFactory.findValue(CoarseSessionFactory.java:127)
    at org.wildfly.clustering.web.infinispan.session.coarse.CoarseSessionFactory.findValue(CoarseSessionFactory.java:56)
    at org.wildfly.clustering.web.infinispan.session.InfinispanSessionManager.findSession(InfinispanSessionManager.java:232)
    at org.wildfly.clustering.web.undertow.session.DistributableSessionManager.getSession(DistributableSessionManager.java:115)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletContextImpl.getSession(ServletContextImpl.java:723)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletContextImpl.getSession(ServletContextImpl.java:753)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletContextImpl.updateSessionAccessTime(ServletContextImpl.java:757)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletResponseImpl.responseDone(HttpServletResponseImpl.java:548)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletResponseImpl.doErrorDispatch(HttpServletResponseImpl.java:162)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:317)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:80)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:172)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:199)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:774)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_66]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_66]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_66]
```

I've trying to run application on wildfly 8.2.1.Final and 9.0.2 Final with openjdk-1.8 and Oracle jdk-1.8 with same result. Application deployed and running with no errors, I'm successfully login and working on servers through load balancer (round robin).

[In undertow sources at github](https://github.com/undertow-io/undertow/blob/master/core/src/main/java/io/undertow/util/HttpString.java) field `hashCode` of class `io.undertow.util.HttpString` declared as `final transient int`. Why `readObject` method trying to change value of this field by very strange way?

I have googled the Internet but found nothing about this or similar error and do not know what to do with it.

Where may be the place in my application which belongs to this exeption?

Update:
This patch for [Undertow server](https://github.com/undertow-io/undertow) helps me to avoid problem:

```
From 7083c4145878f954bbde14f1f6acbb31414c88d9 Mon Sep 17 00:00:00 2001
From: fedor patlin <patlin.f@sovzond.center>
Date: Fri, 18 Dec 2015 15:55:32 +0500
Subject: [PATCH] Set field hashCodeField accessible

---
 core/src/main/java/io/undertow/util/HttpString.java | 2 ++
 1 file changed, 2 insertions(+)

diff --git a/core/src/main/java/io/undertow/util/HttpString.java b/core/src/main/java/io/undertow/util/HttpString.java
index cc75a0b..d21257c 100644
--- a/core/src/main/java/io/undertow/util/HttpString.java
+++ b/core/src/main/java/io/undertow/util/HttpString.java
@@ -335,7 +335,9 @@ public final class HttpString implements Comparable<HttpString>, Serializable {
     private void readObject(ObjectInputStream ois) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
         ois.defaultReadObject();
         try {
+            hashCodeField.setAccessible(true);
             hashCodeField.setInt(this, calcHashCode(bytes));
+            hashCodeField.setAccessible(false);
         } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
             throw new IllegalAccessError(e.getMessage());
         }
-- 
2.5.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed in Wildfly, see [fix](https://github.com/undertow-io/undertow/commit/8a4505bc1cd5a562115fb419c8fc357c00c132c4).